# Как выставить в глобальную обл. вид. метод из замыкания?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, javascript, amd

Есть веб приложение, requirejs, модули: контроллер, виды.

Однажды открывается дочернее окно для авторизации на стороннем сайте. Когда процесс завершен, уже на моём сайте в этом окне выполняется JS, вызывающий метод из родительского окна, т.е. глобальный. Задача вызвать один из методов контроллера.

Пока сделал явно криво. В контроллере:

```
var that = this;
window.cbPublic = function(){
    that.cbPrivate.call( that);
};
```

`cbPrivate` — метод контроллера, который надо в итоге вызвать.

**Как правильно** выставить один из методов контроллера и его контекст в этот глобальный метод?

p.s. что странно, эта кривизна работает, пока все модули отдельны, и перестаёт работать после минификации и сборки r.js  Ещё не разбирался, что именно летит.

Comment: А зачем call? Контест уже that

    that.cbPrivate();

то же самое должно быть.

То, что не работает после минификации, - странно, какой минификатор?

Еще можно так (но тогда для старых ie нужен shim):

    window.cbPublic = this.cbPrivate.bind(this);

Вообще, вы бы сначала var cbPublic в глобальной области объявили бы, а потом присвоили ему то, что я выше написал (без window), или еще можно так, чтобы минификатор не портил window (не будет работать в strict mode):

    var window=(function(){return this})();

Comment: Вообще я, кажется, понял, вот тот модуль, который вы вызываете - передавайте ему параметром этот глобальный cbPublic, т.к. иначе минификатор не будет знать, как минифицировать эту переменную. И тогда вам надо будет всего лишь указать

     cbPublic=this.cbPrivate.bind(this);

Comment: Минификация самая стандартная: `node r.js -o build.js`

Я застрял на элементарном: как в модуль передать параметром этот глобализм?

Comment: http://blog.novanet.no/4-ways-to-pass-parameters-to-requirejs-modules/ ?